# A method or tool to Manipulate Employee's Attendance data

Tags: manual-testing, tools

I'm testing an App with an `Attendance` feature, containing an employee's Arrival Time, Departure, Overtime, etc.

Test Case: If `Attendance` data that has been saved in the database is changed, the relevant employee will get a warning.

I have changed the data via the database, and the warning works properly.

What are some other ways to test this feature or tools I can use to manipulate the data?

Comment: You are asking for tools that can manipulate the data in your database? What database do you use? Pretty much every database has a query language that can "manipulate the data". If yours does, why not use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends**

- Can an employee re-enter their attendance for a date? That's one way to change the data, if it can be done.
- Does the app communicate with an API? You could call the API directly to change the data.
- If you have the ability to run the app with a debugger or using a tool like Fiddler, you could inspect the data the app sends to the database and change it.
- If the app includes an admin function to edit employee attendance you could log onto the app as an administrator and change the data.
- If you know how the database detects that the data is changed, you could try to work around that: if it's using a trigger to flag changes, there's not much you can do, but if it's comparing an archive of inputs vs stored data, you could edit the archive - which would give you a warning without having changed the stored data.

These are just a few suggestions. I'm sure with a bit of imagination you can think of more.